# I can not right click in Delphi7 IDE, because when i click , occur error message

Tags: delphi, crt, msvcr90.dll

I using Delphi 7. Until recently, it worked fine.
But now, every time i do right click, I get an error that message is

> "Access violation at address 735f5e37 in module 'MSVCR90.dll'. Write
>   of address 00000000"

So, I can not do anything in delphi7 IDE for development.

Also, When I left click at menu (such as file, edit, run, tool.. etc) occur same error message.

So, I reinstall delphi7. But same occurs these error message.

Why is this happening?

Comment: Googling "right click error in 'MSVCR90.dll'" finds a number of sites encouraging you to download their tools to fix it, but probably they want you to install their malware.  How recently have you done a full anti-malware scan of your system?  Also, which OS?

Comment: Not very related but you should consider something new (like delphi XE) since your 7 is a bit outdated nowadays

Comment: @AlbertoMiola:  On the other hand, D7's IDE is noticeably faster than and, ime, far more stable than any more recent version of Delphi.

Comment: I doubt Delphi7 needs MSVCR90.dll at all. Sounds more like either your MSVCR90.dll or your system is corrupt for other reasons.

Comment: This is most likely due to a misbehaving third-party component/wizard/extension you've installed, which will not be removed with a simple reinstall of the IDE. See [this answer](http://stackoverflow.com/a/13860652/62576) for a way to see if this is the problem or not and if it is how to fix it.