# "Out of System Resources" error when opening Delphi and clicking on things

Tags: delphi, delphi-ide, eoutofresources

Ever since earlier this week, when I open my Delphi and click on things, I get this popup error. Here's the error details:

> Out of system resources.

```
[79F73147]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.OutOfResources (Line 4432, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 1) + $1C
[79F731EE]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.GDIError (Line 4458, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 13) + $0
[79F73223]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.GDICheck (Line 4463, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 1) + $4
[79F78C73]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.CopyBitmap (Line 7871, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 27) + $17
[79F796B3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.CopyImage (Line 8232, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 13) + $F
[79F7B8D7]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Graphics.TBitmap.SetSize (Line 10012, "Vcl.Graphics.pas" + 10) + $9
[7A0A6C6C]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.WMPaint (Line 7539, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 17) + $14
[7A0A70E5]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.WndProc (Line 7713, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 38) + $6
[7A0A72C6]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TMouseTrackControlStyleHook.WndProc (Line 7812, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 1) + $4
[7A03A63A]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBarStyleHook.WndProc (Line 34652, "Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 6) + $4
[7A0A690A]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleHook.HandleMessage (Line 7418, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 20) + $6
[7A1CAE92]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Styles.TStyleEngine.HandleMessage (Line 3610, "Vcl.Styles.pas" + 22) + $7
[7A0A3338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[79F9B1D3]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.DoHandleStyleMessage (Line 9462, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 0) + $F
[79F9CBE8]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.WndProc (Line 10475, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 1) + $4A
[7A02A1BE]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.ComCtrls.TToolBar.WndProc (Line 25701, "Vcl.ComCtrls.pas" + 104) + $6
[79F9C700]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Controls.TWinControl.MainWndProc (Line 10321, "Vcl.Controls.pas" + 3) + $6
[7B285C1C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18517, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[7A0E5263]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11488, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[7A0E528E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages (Line 11510, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[00D777FF]{bds.exe     } AppMain.TAppBuilder.ApplicationActivated (Line 2750, "AppMain.pas" + 0) + $7
[7A13F0EB]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.DoActivate (Line 210, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 1) + $12
[7A13F78D]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.DoActivate (Line 438, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 5) + $C
[7A0E4713]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.WndProc (Line 11063, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 140) + $C
[7B170E36]{rtl280.bpl  } System.TMonitor.Exit (Line 20101, "System.pas" + 2) + $7
[7B281724]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.CheckSynchronize (Line 15817, "System.Classes.pas" + 66) + $5
[06146E97]{fmx280.bpl  } FMX.Platform.Win.TPlatformWin.ThreadSync (Line 3503, "FMX.Platform.Win.pas" + 3) + $2
[7B285C1C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18517, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[7A0A3338]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Themes.TStyleManager.HandleMessage (Line 5872, "Vcl.Themes.pas" + 11) + $11
[7A0E5263]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11488, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[7A0E528E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages (Line 11510, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[00D777FF]{bds.exe     } AppMain.TAppBuilder.ApplicationActivated (Line 2750, "AppMain.pas" + 0) + $7
[7A13F0EB]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TCustomApplicationEvents.DoActivate (Line 210, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 1) + $12
[7A13F78D]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.AppEvnts.TMultiCaster.DoActivate (Line 438, "Vcl.AppEvnts.pas" + 5) + $C
[7A0E4713]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.WndProc (Line 11063, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 140) + $C
[7B285C1C]{rtl280.bpl  } System.Classes.StdWndProc (Line 18517, "System.Classes.pas" + 8) + $0
[7A0E5263]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessage (Line 11488, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 23) + $1
[7A0E528E]{vcl280.bpl  } Vcl.Forms.TApplication.ProcessMessages (Line 11510, "Vcl.Forms.pas" + 1) + $4
[00DC8090]{bds.exe     } bds.bds (Line 224, "" + 13) + $2
```

This is how the error popup looks. It is just a big error popup over my Delphi:

[image: Delphi Error - Out of system resources.]

I have tried to uninstall components and reinstall components, but no difference. I do not know what is causing the error.

My computer's resources are not overloaded either. I have enough resources

[image: Computer Performance]

---

What is causing this? How can I fix it?

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551). Also, *click on things* is a pretty useless problem description. Have you tried removing the third-party components you have installed to see if the problem goes away? For a way to debug this easily, see [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/13860652/62576). Also, did you click on the **Details** button in the error dialog?

Comment: `Out of System Resources` doesn't mean running out of memory. Most likely your system is running out of Handles. You can se number of opened handles in your system by opening task manager and checking detailed view of CPU usage. What happens if you restart your computer and open only Delphi? Based on your screenshot from TaskManager I'm guessing you had many programs opened because Delphi as 32 bit application could never use more than 3.5 GB of RAM and yet your RAM usage was above 26 GB.  ...

Comment: ... Also I see you had high CPU and high primary SSD usage which makes me believe that your Anti Virus software might be doing a scan at that specific time. But then again moderate GPU usage might indicate that you had some game opened in the background.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I could not get this working at all.

The solution was to **completely uninstall Delphi** and **reinstall Delphi** from scratch.

Once I reinstalled Delphi, it was working perfectly fine without any errors and exceptions